# Check if script is run via a powershell terminal?

Tags: python, powershell, user-experience

I am writing a generic script that can be run by a user, or via a script.  I want to set it up so that when a user double-clicks the script, they can see the output, but if they run in the terminal, there is no prompt for input.  For this reason, in my script's arguments, I set it up the following way:

```
import argparse
import os

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument(
    '--interactive', '-i', action='store_true',
    default='PROMPT' not in os.environ,
    help='put the application in interactive mode'
)
args = parser.parse_args()

# Do Stuff

if args.interactive:
    input('Press enter to continue...')
```

This default rule (checking `'PROMPT' not in os.environ`) works perfect for regular command line and batch scripts, as PROMPT gets automatically set.  However, it does not work with Powershell.  Is there a way to determine if the script has been run in a Powershell environment, so as to provide a similar solution of *not* being interactive without the user needing to specify anything?

I know the user can run the script this way in powershell:

```
$env:PROMPT = "NotTheEmptyString"; py .\test.py
```

However, this seems like a poor interface, and I don't know powershell well enough to check for things in the environment.

Comment: you can add a test for `$Host`. that will error out in cmd, but will give you the PoSh host if in powershell.